# psql configure database ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: postgresql, psql

I could see the error is about the brackets in dragon.sql CREATE TABLE dragon etc...but I don't how/what to fix...thanks.

Below are terminal running log, configure_db.sh and the dragon.sql file

```
> backend@1.0.0 configure
> sh ./bin/configure_db.sh

Configuring dragonstackdb
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 4: );
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 7: );
        ^
dragonstackdb configured

------------------------------------
configure_db.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Configuring dragonstackdb"
dropdb -U node_user dragonstackdb
createdb -U node_user dragonstackdb

psql -U node_user dragonstackdb < ./bin/sql/generation.sql
psql -U node_user dragonstackdb < ./bin/sql/dragon.sql

echo "dragonstackdb configured"
-------------------------------
dragon.sql
CREATE TABLE dragon (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   birthdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   nickname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   "generationId" INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY ("generationId") REFERENCES generation(id),
);
```

Comment: You have a trailing `,` before the closing `);` in `dragon.sql`

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREIGN KEY ("generationId") REFERENCES generation(id),
```

Remove the comma at the end. Having a comma means it should have another line (i.e. another column).

This should be the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dragon (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   birthdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   nickname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   "generationId" INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY ("generationId") REFERENCES generation(id)
);
```

Here's an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp).